# UMP test and non-decreasing power function

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, optimal

Let $\phi$ be a UMP test for $H_o: \theta \leq \theta_0$ and $H_1: \theta > \theta_0$. Let its power function, $E_\theta(\phi)$, be differentiable w.r.t. $\theta$.

Show the power function is non-decreasing in $\theta$.

I can understand why size should always be less than power in this case, but why does it have to be non-decreasing?

Comment: Think of it this way.  As $\theta$ gets larger, the null hypothesis gets "more wrong".  Therefore, one would hope, the power of the test is greater for larger $\theta$, or at the very least not smaller - hence the "non-decreasing" property.  Proving that this is the case for a UMP is the math part of the question.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but there's a bit more to it than that. The differentiability (or at least continuity) of the power function seems to be needed to stop you just defining $\theta$ to be a non-monotone function of the "actual" parameter.  Compare to $N(\mu,1)$ with $\theta=\mu$ for $\mu\leq 0$ and $\theta=1/\mu$ for $\mu>0$.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that $\mathcal F=\{f_{\theta}:\theta\in \Omega\}$ is a family of identifiable distributions having [monotone likelihood ratio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/521710/119261) in some statistic $T(x)$. The Karlin-Rubin theorem then states that for testing $H_0:\theta\le \theta_0$ against $H_1:\theta>\theta_0$, there exists a UMP size $\alpha$ test of the form $\phi=\mathbf1_{\{T>c\}}+\gamma\mathbf1_{\{T=c\}}$ for every $\alpha\in (0,1)$.

Now consider testing $H:\theta=\theta_1'$ against $K:\theta=\theta_2'$ where $\theta_2'>\theta_1'$. Then $\phi$ is most powerful for this testing problem. [So](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3795982/321264) it is also an unbiased test (its power is at least its size), i.e. $E_{\theta_2'}\phi\ge E_{\theta_1'}\phi$. In fact, strict inequality holds due to identifiability of $\mathcal F$: $$E_{\theta_2'}\phi> E_{\theta_1'}\phi$$

As $\theta_1'$ and $\theta_2'$ are arbitrary, the above holds for every $\theta_2'>\theta_1'$. This makes the power function $E_{\theta}\phi$ strictly increasing in $\theta$. For details, you can refer to page 5 of the lecture notes [here](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/jaw/COURSES/580s/581/LECTNOTES/ch6a.pdf).

I don't think differentiability of power function is needed for proving this under the above setup.

Comment: I think you're right; the assumption of a monotone likelihood ratio would seem to make differentiability of the power function superfluous.

Comment: Why can we safely assume the existence of MLR?

Comment: @WilliamAmbrose I think it's a reasonable assumption since it guarantees existence of a UMP test for $H_0$ vs $H_1$.